# Add values to a new column based on previous year in R

Tags: r, date

I want to add a new column PPR which means prior to prior year details to data. Which means if the year is 2020 I want to add 2018 data to PPR. My data is as follows,

```
Company = c("ABC", "ABC", "ABC", "XYZ", "XYZ", "XYZ", "KJF", "KJF", "KJF", "KJF")
Year = c(2021, 2020, 2019, 2017, 2018, 2019, 2020, 2019, 2021, 2018)
REC = c(100, 200, 300, 3000, 4000, 2000, 5000, 6000, 7000, 8000)
data = data.frame(Company, Year, REC, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

I want to achieve this [Highlighted in yellow.

[image]

Since dates are involved, I tried this out

```
library(lubridate)
data$Year = as.Date(data$Year)

dat = data %>% 
  group_by(Company) %>% 
  mutate(PPR = ifelse(Year == Year, Year %m+% years(2), Year))
```

I couldn't achieve this. Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Year - 2` value as lookup using `match` for each `Company`.

```
library(dplyr)

data %>%
  group_by(Company) %>%
  mutate(PPR = REC[match(Year - 2, Year)]) %>%
  ungroup

#  Company  Year   REC   PPR
#   <chr>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1 ABC      2021   100   300
# 2 ABC      2020   200    NA
# 3 ABC      2019   300    NA
# 4 XYZ      2017  3000    NA
# 5 XYZ      2018  4000    NA
# 6 XYZ      2019  2000  3000
# 7 KJF      2020  5000  8000
# 8 KJF      2019  6000    NA
# 9 KJF      2021  7000  6000
#10 KJF      2018  8000    NA
```

Comment: The answer works perfectly fine. Now if I want to loop through a set of variables and find the prior to prior value, it's quite confusing to use mutate inside a loop. I have tried this, fnames is the vactor on which I have to loop, example fnames = c("REC", "S"), ``` for(i in 1:length(fnames)) {
  j = fnames[i]
    yrTmp = match(Year - 2, Year, nomatch = 0)
  data[, sprintf("PP%s", j)] = data[data[, j], yrTmp] 
  print(paste("PP", j, "calculated")) 
  }``` Can you help me with this?

Comment: Sorry, this is not clear for me. Can you ask this as a new question?

Comment: Yes! I will create a new question.

Comment: I've asked framed a new question here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68846602/add-new-variables-using-mutate-by-looping-through-a-vector-inside-a-for-loop-in

Answer (score 1):

It would be easy to sort your data and the use `dplyr::lag()` to grab the values

```
data %>% 
  group_by(Company) %>% 
  arrange(Year, .by_group=TRUE) %>% 
  mutate(PRR = lag(REC, 2))
```

If you are missing any years for a company, you can use `tidyr::complete` to fill them in

```
data %>% 
  group_by(Company) %>% 
  tidyr::complete(Year=seq(min(Year), max(Year))) %>% 
  arrange(Year, .by_group=TRUE) %>% 
  mutate(PRR = lag(REC, 2))
```

And if you really need to keep the original order, you can add that value in and sort again at the end

```
data %>% 
  mutate(idx = row_number()) %>% 
  group_by(Company) %>% 
  tidyr::complete(Year=seq(min(Year), max(Year))) %>% 
  arrange(Year, .by_group=TRUE) %>% 
  mutate(PRR = lag(REC, 2)) %>% 
  arrange(idx) %>% select(-idx)
```

which returns

```
   Company  Year   REC   PRR
   <chr>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
 1 ABC      2021   100   300
 2 ABC      2020   200    NA
 3 ABC      2019   300    NA
 4 XYZ      2017  3000    NA
 5 XYZ      2018  4000    NA
 6 XYZ      2019  2000  3000
 7 KJF      2020  5000  8000
 8 KJF      2019  6000    NA
 9 KJF      2021  7000  6000
10 KJF      2018  8000    NA
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
df <- data.frame(Company=data$Company)
df$Year <- data$Year - 2
df <- merge(df, data, by=c('Company', 'Year'))
df$Year <- df$Year + 2
data <- merge(data, df, by=c('Company', 'Year'), all.x=TRUE)
```