# Add new variables using mutate by looping through a vector inside a for loop in r

Tags: r, for-loop, dplyr

I'm working with a dataset where it requires me to add prior to prior year data for a column. I want to add the prior to prior year data for not only one column but a list of columns. This is what I've tried,

```
Company = c("ABC", "ABC", "ABC", "XYZ", "XYZ", "XYZ", "KJF", "KJF", "KJF", "KJF")
Year = c(2021, 2020, 2019, 2017, 2018, 2019, 2020, 2019, 2021, 2018)
REC = c(100, 200, 300, 3000, 4000, 2000, 5000, 6000, 7000, 8000)
S   = c(1000, 2000, 3000, 300, 400, 200, 500, 600, 700, 800)
data = data.frame(Company, Year, REC, S, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

fnames = c("REC", "S")
prevYear = 3

  for(i in 1:length(fnames)) {
  j = fnames[i]
  
  yrTmp = match(Year - prevYear, Year, nomatch = 0)
  data[, sprintf("PP%s", j)] = 
    data = data %>%
    group_by(Company) %>%
    mutate(data[, sprintf("PP%s", j)] = data[data[, j], yrTmp]) %>%
    ungroup 
  
  print(paste("PP", j, "calculated"))
  
  }
```

I want to add prior to prior year data to REC and S using this loop. In future I want to add more than 40 variables using this loop. How can I achieve it using for loop?
This is the desired output,[image]

Comment: Can you please add your desired output!  I feel that this can be done without using any loop

Comment: I've added the desired output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `across` to apply a function to multiple columns.

```
library(dplyr)

data %>%
  group_by(Company) %>%
  mutate(across(all_of(fnames), ~.[match(Year - prevYear, Year)], 
         .names = 'PP_{col}')) %>%
  ungroup
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution. I tried to run this in my environment and it isn't giving me the right column names. I will try to solve this issue.

Comment: This does give the expected output for the data shared so maybe in your actual data there is something different.

Comment: Yes but the column names are getting populated correctly.

Comment: If you don't want underscore in the names you can change `.names = 'PP_{col}` to `.names = 'PP{col}`

Comment: But the column names are not get populated correctly. I'm getting answers like this , PP_.col. and NA. But I expect it to be PPREC and PPS.

Comment: That's strange. that doesn't happen for me. Using the code from my answer and data from the question I get `PP_REC` and `PP_S`. What version of `dplyr` package are you using I have 1.0.7. Maybe you need to update it. You can check the package version with `packageVersion('dplyr')`

Comment: Yes you're right. My version of dplyr is 0.8.3. I should update it then.